# Frequent grpc discovery.Discovery, callChaincode, QueryChaincodeDefinition logs in hyperledger fabric peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

A hyperldger fabric network with two peers and 3 orderers, chain code got installed in both peers, everything works fine, but I see following logs on the peers, Is there anybody who can tell what going on?

**Peer-1** shows a lot of frequent **discovery.Discovery** logs that keep coming.

**Peer-2** showing also a lot of callChaincode, QueryChaincodeDefinition logs, but no Txns is coming, nothing got invoked on-chain code

**Peer-1**

```
2022-02-22 07:10:03.291 UTC 8272 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.request_deadline=2022-02-22T07:10:18.29Z grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:52930 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=369.752µs
2022-02-22 07:10:03.292 UTC 8273 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.request_deadline=2022-02-22T07:10:18.29Z grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:52930 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.846248ms
2022-02-22 07:10:08.296 UTC 8274 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.request_deadline=2022-02-22T07:10:23.295Z grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:52930 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=365.531µs
2022-02-22 07:10:08.296 UTC 8275 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.request_deadline=2022-02-22T07:10:23.295Z grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:52930 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=1.049292ms
2022-02-22 07:10:13.300 UTC 8276 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.request_deadline=2022-02-22T07:10:28.299Z grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:52930 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=534.941µs
2022-02-22 07:10:13.301 UTC 8277 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.request_deadline=2022-02-22T07:10:28.299Z grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:52930 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=656.879µs
2022-02-22 07:10:18.305 UTC 8278 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.request_deadline=2022-02-22T07:10:33.304Z grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:52930 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=295.207µs
2022-02-22 07:10:18.306 UTC 8279 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=discovery.Discovery grpc.method=Discover grpc.request_deadline=2022-02-22T07:10:33.304Z grpc.peer_address=172.26.0.1:52930 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=691.75µs
```

**Peer-2**

```
2022-02-22 07:18:11.393 UTC a78c INFO [lifecycle] QueryChaincodeDefinition -> Successfully queried chaincode name 'sumitcc' with definition {sequence: 1, endorsement info: (version: '1.0', plugin: 'escc', init required: false), validation info: (plugin: 'vscc', policy: '12202f4368616e6e656c2f4170706c69636174696f6e2f456e646f7273656d656e74'), collections: ()},
2022-02-22 07:18:11.394 UTC a78d INFO [endorser] callChaincode -> finished chaincode: _lifecycle duration: 4ms channel=sumit txID=b67a8f4a
2022-02-22 07:18:11.394 UTC a78e INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.100.124.44:55586 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=5.094712ms
2022-02-22 07:18:11.407 UTC a78f INFO [endorser] callChaincode -> finished chaincode: lscc duration: 2ms channel=sumit txID=e6d3966f
2022-02-22 07:18:11.407 UTC a790 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.100.124.44:55586 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=3.485798ms
2022-02-22 07:18:11.415 UTC a791 INFO [lifecycle] QueryChaincodeDefinition -> Successfully queried chaincode name 'sumitcc' with definition {sequence: 1, endorsement info: (version: '1.0', plugin: 'escc', init required: false), validation info: (plugin: 'vscc', policy: '12202f4368616e6e656c2f4170706c69636174696f6e2f456e646f7273656d656e74'), collections: ()},
2022-02-22 07:18:11.416 UTC a792 INFO [endorser] callChaincode -> finished chaincode: _lifecycle duration: 3ms channel=sumit txID=b2da61c8
2022-02-22 07:18:11.416 UTC a793 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.100.124.44:55586 grpc.peer_subject="CN=fabric-common" grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=4.619323ms
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries. It's just a background work needed by peers to keep their MSP updated. I believe one is anchor peer while the other one is trying to get updated with a time interval. You may tune the log level to debug tho, it is good enough for learning HLF.

Comment: Understood, because one peer is anchor peer so that guy getting all such updates and another peer not, got it.